# 2006 Ford Fusion - High Oil Consumption

Tags: ford, oil, fusion

My 2006 Ford Fusion (4 cylinder, manual transmission) is using a lot of oil.

1 qt every 300 miles.  No smoke, no oil spots under the car on the garage floor.

***Where could  the oil be going?***

Comment: Have you looked in your radiator?

Comment: how many times have you added a qt of oil since your last oil change?

Comment: 1.  No sign of oil in the antifreeze.

Comment: We've added 5 quarts since the last oil change, 1500 miles ago.

Comment: Is the engine bay oily? maybe its an oil seal or a gasket

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have oil in your coolant, the only option for the oil to go would be is through the exhaust and out, make sure the pcv valve is not bad not stuck closed not shorted out, the oil in the exhaust might not be noticeable.